# CI Server on XCodeCloud using Rswift stops with the following error “RswiftGenerateInternalResources” is disabled

Tags: swift

I have an application being build with XCode cloud.

I have just updated Rswift to version 7.4.0.

I have added the build tool plugin
[image]

However when running on XCode clound the build is failing with

> “RswiftGenerateInternalResources” is disabled

So from the documentation at https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift/blob/main/Documentation/Migration.md#configuring-continuous-integration-system upgrading to 7.0 using Swift PM, apart from the last step to run RswiftXcodeModifyPackages, which I have no way of doing via XCode Cloud that I am aware of.

So is anybody able to provide a suggestion on how to have RSWift generate on XCode Cloud.

The build environment is
[image]

EDIT

I overcame this by adding a ci_scripts/ci_post_clone script to my build with the contents:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDESkipPackagePluginFingerprintValidatation -bool YES
```

The error I am receiving is

```
Error: You don’t have permission to save the file “R.generated.swift” in the folder “Resources”.
```

I have tried things like creating a top level Resources folder, using shell script to ci_post_clone.sh to create the folder, all to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be fixed soon in a new version of R.swift when this PR is merged:

https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift/pull/879

> Fixes #862
>
> The RswiftCore implementation can be found at try contents.write(to:
> outputURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8) is used to write the
> generated code; if atomically is true, the content is written to an
> intermediate file and then moved to the outputURL. However, XocdeCloud
> does not seem to allow writing outside of the pluginWorkDirectory,
> even for temporary files created by the Foundation framework.
>
> The easiest way to make Build succeed on Xcode Cloud seems to be to
> change "atomically" to false.
>
> What do you think about changing it?
>
> References liamnichols/xcstrings-tool#36
>
> https://zenn.dev/hiragram/articles/49f178b58a36bc (Written in
> Japanese)